# I'm having issues preparing column name as parameter using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I've been working with this query to achieve the results I wanted, which I have. During this time I started using PDO and at first worked by just having one varibale to prepare inside the query. While testing, I ended up using two more variables inside the query but left them out of the prepared statement until I was finished.

Now that I have the query completed, I went on and tried preparing the three variables as I did with the first one but an error was displayed when I ran the query:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '':cdrLastTable'
> ON a.`id` = b.`source_customer_billing_zone_' at line 2

I noticed the error was coming from one of the three prepared variables I needed for my query, but the thing is that the one that's failing is the only one placed before the `WHERE` clause. Excluding it from the prepared statement works fine. After reading and looking at exaples I could not find any with a variable before the `WHERE` clause so my question is:

Can you prepare variables before the `WHERE` clause? If this is not possible, then what would be the point on using `PDO` for this query?

I'm assuming that this issue does not relate to the query or any syntax error since removing the variable from the prepared statement just works, but I could be wrong as well.

This is the query with all variables prepared (the one that gives off the error):

```php
$stmtOutgoing = $connAccounting->prepare("SELECT a.`zone` AS zone, init_time, a.`detail` AS sku, b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, count(*) AS llamadas, SUM((CEIL(b.`duration`))) AS duracion, SUM((b.`source_customer_cost`)/100) AS total, SUM((b.`source_customer_cost`)/100)/(SUM((CEIL(b.`duration`)))) AS precio 
                                        FROM `billing`.billing_zones_history a INNER JOIN :cdrLastTable 
                                        ON a.`id` = b.`source_customer_billing_zone_id` 
                                        WHERE source_external_subscriber_id = :source_external_subscriber_id AND init_time >= :queryLastTstmp
                                        GROUP BY a.`detail` 
                                        ORDER BY total desc");
                        $stmtOutgoing->execute(array('source_external_subscriber_id' => $source_external_subscriber_id, 'cdrLastTable' => $cdrLastTable, 'queryLastTstmp' => $queryLastTstmp));
```

You can see the error message points directly at `:cdrLastTable` right after the `INNER JOIN`, and effectively removing it like this:

```php
$stmtOutgoing = $connAccounting->prepare("SELECT a.`zone` AS zone, init_time, a.`detail` AS sku, b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, count(*) AS llamadas, SUM((CEIL(b.`duration`))) AS duracion, SUM((b.`source_customer_cost`)/100) AS total, SUM((b.`source_customer_cost`)/100)/(SUM((CEIL(b.`duration`)))) AS precio 
                                        FROM `billing`.billing_zones_history a INNER JOIN $cdrLastTable 
                                        ON a.`id` = b.`source_customer_billing_zone_id` 
                                        WHERE source_external_subscriber_id = :source_external_subscriber_id AND init_time >= :queryLastTstmp
                                        GROUP BY a.`detail` 
                                        ORDER BY total desc");
                        $stmtOutgoing->execute(array('source_external_subscriber_id' => $source_external_subscriber_id, 'queryLastTstmp' => $queryLastTstmp));
```

Makes the statement work.

For some context:

A new table is created each month, hence the need to store the name in a variable unlike the first table which has a 'static' name.

The server is running `10.3.23-MariaDB` and `PHP 7.2.33`.

I have tried quoting the variable like this: `':cdrLastTable'` but did not work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Identifiers (column/table names) cannot be bound as parameters (only for values).

Comment: there is no point in having a variable table name in the first place

Comment: I need to store it inside a variable because a new table is generated each month, the name uses the current Ym, for example, the name of the tabe for this month would be cdr_202010 but this is one of two querys. This one is for values from the past month (cdr_202009) so I need to generate the table's name using code depending on the current date. Is there other way to do it without using a variable? would the second query pose a possible entry point for sql injection?

Comment: Note about the other query: they are both identical other than the two variable names (cdrLastTable would be cdrCurrentTable for exaple), that's why I only posted one but I'm having the same issue on both

Comment: @Berny If your `$cdrLastTable` variable is safe (not coming from user input) then you can use it directly like in your second query.

Comment: Yeah it's safe, that variable is generated via code whenever the query is run. Thank you all for clearing this up!

Comment: because it makes you to add a useless variable in your query and put you in a fix? where it must be just another condition in the WHERE

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge but I don't see how to do what you propose. I need the table for the INNER JOIN for I need data belonging to two different tables. Each month the second table 'closes' and automatically a new one is created. These tables store call info, so with each billing cycle there is a new tabe. I do not have direct control over this matter, however I could present this other way of doing it. What you suggest is to store everything on one table period and access relevant data for the current cycle using `where` clause?

Comment: Why are you creating a whole new table every month instead of just storing which month it is in a column in a single table? Variable tables are almost never the best way to do it.

Comment: I see @GrumpyCrouton, when I arrived at this project all this infrastructure had already been in place for a couple of years, that's why I have no direct control control over it. I just rolled with what was established. I will aks why is the db system designed like so and perhaps I can share what I learned here. At first it made sense for my due to my lack of laboral experience and the fact of the company being a telephone one with billing cycles. I even tought it was a smart move! Nontheless, huge thanks for clarifying this up!

Comment: @Berny Yeah, having multiple tables like this is bad for a few reasons. 1) Tables themselves have more overhead than just adding more rows, so your storage space is being wasted (It's not a huge deal because of how cheap storage can be...) and 2) It makes doing queries like this much much harder and less safe for no real gain.